# Using a 3rd Party SAN Cert for LDAPS --- Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate, ldap

For various reasons, we have decided not to stand up an internal CA, and will be using a 3rd Party (GoDaddy) SAN Certificate for various internal sites, and for securing LDAP in preparation for the *March 2020 Microsoft Updates that will block non-encrypted LDAP traffic.*

To save money, we would like to purchase a SAN cert, but I am reading conflicting documentation on whether this will work for our use case (2x DCs).

**Petri's documentation says:**

`...the first name in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) must match the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) of the host machine`

**Whereas Microsoft's documentations says:**

`The Active Directory fully qualified domain name of the domain controller (for example, DC01.DOMAIN.COM) must appear in one of the following places...
DNS entry in the Subject Alternative Name extension.`

Microsoft does not specify that it must be the *first* entry.

If I understand correctly, since we would want to use this cert on **both** domain controllers, both hostnames couldn't possibly be listed first.

**Which source is correct?**

https://www.petri.com/enable-secure-ldap-windows-server-2008-2012-dc

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321051/how-to-enable-ldap-over-ssl-with-a-third-party-certification-authority

Comment: Didn't see what Petri says, but Microsoft source is correct. BTW, if your AD domain isn't registered in internet, you won't be able to purchase certificate for private domain.

Comment: @Crypt32 We use a subdomain ad.companyname.com of our domain which is registered on the internet.  

So are you saying we can in fact have CompanyDC1 and CompanyDC2 listed anywhere in the SAN field, and it will work for LDAPS?  

I quoted what Petri said in my OP so you don't have to click the link.

Comment: Correct. When two sources conflict, authoritative source must be used. Microsoft is authoritative for their products, Petri isn't. There is no question whom to trust.

Comment: Even microsoft has conflicting documentation on this matter.  Another MS article (albeit older) agrees with the Petri doc. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2980.ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-certificate.aspx